# A movie or play about a traveling salesman selling little atomic bombs to a family

Tags: story-identification, movie, theater-play

The film or play was about a traveling salesman who wants to sell a little atomic bomb to a family to destroy their bad neighbor.

Can anyone tell me the name of this story?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)